# why do I get different results with kill -0 (<jobspec>|pid)

Tags: bash

I am writing a script that will launch another process and after a period of time kill it if it hasn't exited on its own.  Since starting this, I came to realize that the `timeout` command is the right way to do this, but I'm still confused about why one of my approaches was failing.

Here's what I was trying:

```
#!/bin/bash

backgroundScript.sh &

for((i=0; i<60; i++)); do
    if ! kill -0 %1; then
        exit
    fi
    sleep 1
done

kill %1
```

I was surprised to find that `kill -0 %1` was always succeeding, even when the process in the background finished.  If I used the PID for that process, so the `if` within the loop became:

```
    if ! kill -0 $!; then
```

it worked fine.  So why wasn't the jobspec working for me there?

Comment: Sending signal 0 via the [`kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) system call only checks whether the process exists; it doesn't actually send any signal to the process.

Comment: Right, but the job in %1 had terminated so the process did not exist, although the job still did seemingly since testing the pid and jobspec behave differently

Comment: I could reproduce the behaviour.  Adding a call to `jobs` in the loop changed the behaviour, depending on the position of the `jobs` call (sometimes it aborted as expected, sometimes the bug of not-aborting remained).  Also, sourcing vs. calling the script (`(. ./x.sh)` vs. `(./x.sh)`) evades the bug.  I'd call the mechanism of `kill -0 %1` brittle.  One more thing: `strace` showed that in the bug case the `kill` wasn't even executed, even if it was debug printed (via `set -x`).

Comment: The shell does not remember which processes have already terminated, it's hard to work around this restriction.

Comment: ...for that matter, job control is off by default in scripts (more generally, in interactive shells) -- and the script here is doing nothing to reenable it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy could you please elaborate on the job control being off?  Why does it seem that the `kill %1` line works while the `kill -0 %1` does not?  I would have expected those to either both work or neither work, but perhaps you can point me toward some more reading about this?

Comment: @FUZxxl I'm not sure I quite follow what it's not remembering.  Shouldn't `kill -0` have it go test it?  Though clearly, it seems, the job can outlive the process, so perhaps that's what you're saying, jobs don't get reaped predictably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a bunch of digging I have uncovered why `kill -0 %1` shows the job still exists while `kill -0 $!` shows the process has exited.  bash will not reap the job until the caller has been notified.  In an interactive shell that will print to the screen the job termination.  In a non-interactive shell, this means the calling script has had a chance to get the return value of the process.

One of the relevant comments that tipped me off from the bash source is in jobs.c:

> /* Mark all dead jobs as notified, so delete_job () cleans them out
>      of the job table properly.  POSIX.2 says we need to save the
>      status of the last CHILD_MAX jobs, so we count the number of dead
>      jobs and mark only enough as notified to save CHILD_MAX statuses. */

And in the `wait_for_single_pid` function this snippet:

```
/* POSIX.2: if we just waited for a job, we can remove it from the jobs
 table. */
BLOCK_CHILD (set, oset);
job = find_job (pid, 0, NULL);
if (job != NO_JOB && jobs[job] && DEADJOB (job))
  jobs[job]->flags |= J_NOTIFIED;
UNBLOCK_CHILD (oset);
```

Until the caller has been notified that the job is done, it is not done.  The process related to it might be done, but the job itself is not done.

Answer (score 2):

Job control in general, and specifically job specifications like `%1`, are not portable. The common approach is to save the PID from `$!` to a variable, and use that as the argument to `kill`.

Comment: Well, as I noted `timeout` seems to be the real way to do what I want, I just wanted to know why `kill -0 $!` worked and `kill -0 %1` did not, so I don't think this really addresses my question

Comment: Huh? I don't see how this could be explained more clearly. `%1` only works iff the shell has job control enabled. Though I can speculate that `kill` ends up with a funny and/or unpredictable argument list when arguably it should fail with an error message when you try to use a jobspec when job control is not available.

Comment: But `kill %1` does work, just `kill -0 %1` is unreliable.  Also, I'm not asking how to use `kill` to accomplish this task portably or otherwise, I'm asking why `kill` works differently when passed two arguments that are tightly related (a jobspec and the PID of the process in that job).  I agree that using `$!` would be the way to go if I were still trying to use `kill` to reinvent `timeout` (which I was initially), but that's not my question.  So you can in fact kill a jobspec without using `set -m`.