# BASH - After 'wait', why does 'jobs -p' sometimes show 'Done' for a background process?

Tags: bash, shell, background, wait, jobs

The short version: My bash script has a function.

This function then launches several instances (a maximum of 10) of another function in the background (with `&`).

I keep a count of how many are still active with `jobs -p | wc -w` in a do loop. When I'm done with the loop, I `break`.

I then use `wait` to ensure that all those processes terminate before continuing.

However, when I check the count (with `jobs -p`) I *sometimes* find this:

```
[10]   9311 Done                    my_background_function_name $param
```

How can I get `wait` to only proceed when all the launched child-processes have completely terminated and the jobs list is empty?

Why are jobs sometimes shown with "Done" and sometimes not?

Clearly, my knowledge of how `jobs` works is deficient. :)

Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to wait, why check with `jobs -p` why not just jump to the `wait` since it'll wait for all the children?

Comment: Though not the same, I had been confused ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757422/why-do-i-get-different-results-with-kill-0-jobspecpid)) by the relationship between jobs and processes.  They are definitely different, so it's not necessarily safe to intermingle your ideas about them too much, jobs can continue even when the process is gone, although that's not the problem you have here, I just highlight that they are not interchangable

Comment: `jobs -p` forms part of an on-screen progress display to let user know how many copies of that background function are still active. After `wait` it runs again to ensure progress now reads "0". But sometimes it doesn't. I don't know why. Maybe I should parse `jobs` output and count the number of jobs listed as 'Running' only?

Comment: @EricRenouf - yes, I'm definitely confused. I usually use PIDs but looked like `jobs -p` might be a better solution here. Now I'm not sure. :)

Comment: Could you post more of your code?  It'll likely make it easier to disentangle

Comment: @EricRenouf  - ah, no, that would just make it much worse... lol... Just wondered why jobs sometimes shows "Done" for background jobs and sometimes doesn't. I've had a read of your link - and I learned something new. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114396/discussion-between-eric-renouf-and-teracow).

Comment: A job, by definition, is a pipeline, which may consist of multiple processes.

Comment: I think I'll have to count the number of 'Running' jobs in `jobs` as this should give me the right figure. My current method is a bit buggy. :)

Comment: Wrote this earlier and it has been working well: `count=$(jobs -l | grep Running | wc -l)` Doesn't answer my original query, though... :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside a bash script, it seems that when all jobs has ended, jobs -p still returns the last one finished.
This works for me in bash:

```
while true; do
  sleep 5
  jobs_running=($(jobs -l | grep Running | awk '{print $2}'))
  if [ ${#jobs_running[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    break
  fi
  echo "Jobs running: ${jobs_running[@]}"
done
```

Using the "wait" command you cannot tell when each process ends.
With the previous algorithm you can.

Comment: I like this, but I had to change it a bit, because "jobs -l" is language dependent (or use LANT=C before command), but there is a "jobs -r" for only running jobs, but does not return the pid, but the jobID at $1. So I changed only one line to:
jobs_running=($(jobs -r | awk '{print $1}'))